# Add margin between row elements bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 different elements in my row class with bootstrap. I wish to create a margin (of 20px for example) between EACH of the elements in the row container. Since the elements are divided into 4 equal spaces of the row container (on the same line), adding a margin class with a margin parameter of 20px pushes the other elements to the next line (whereas I want to keep them all in the same line).

My current code

```
<div class="row">
      <a style="display:block" href="#">
        <div class="col-sm-4 margin">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
          <h4>About Us</h4>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a style="display:block" href="#">
        <div class="col-sm-4 margin">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
          <h4>Contacts</h4>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a style="display:block" href="#">
        <div class="col-sm-4 margin">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
          <h4>Upcoming Events</h4>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: How about adding a `padding` to `.col-sm-4`, and set .col-sm-4 to `box-sizing: border-box;`. See this example: https://jsfiddle.net/pe0w20kd/ Is this what you want?

Comment: If I had a padding and the box-sizing to the margin, I can see that the containers are still side by side (I've added a border around the elements which is how I can see).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed the structure to a more proper one I think. And I use `padding` on `h4` element.

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/18789/)

```
    <div class="row">          
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <h4 class="margin">
            <a style="display:block" href="#">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
                About Us
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <h4 class="margin">
            <a style="display:block" href="#">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
                About Us
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <h4 class="margin">
            <a style="display:block" href="#">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
                About Us
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is indeed what I want. I've tweaked it a little bit as well to include a border around each element block.

Comment: You're welcome. I think it's better to not overload bootstrap classes by adding fixes on it and preferable to change elements in it :)

Comment: I agree. Best to keep the code nice, clean and simple!

Answer (score 1):

Created a fiddle to make things clear .
https://fiddle.jshell.net/q1je1kct/  
Is this you wanted 
Added 
`display:inline-block;`
**Update**

https://fiddle.jshell.net/q1je1kct/4/

If you don't want the elements jumping to newline , take a look into this 

https://fiddle.jshell.net/q1je1kct/5/

Created using flex concept.

**new Update as suggested** 
https://fiddle.jshell.net/q1je1kct/8/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, with your latest update, even I hover over the elements, I can still see that they are side by side (in terms of clicking on the links). I'd like to have a gap between the elements, as in if I hover over the space in between, it wouldn't show me the hand link (i.e the way the cursor changes to a hand when you hover over a link). So even though visually there is a gap, the elements are still not spaced out.

Comment: I've tried your code and it works the way I've wanted it to with just a few modifications. I've accepted the other answer simply because it seems a "cleaner" way to represent the code. Thank you for your help.