# how to give row's elements margin without breaking the row?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

How can I add margin between elements without breaking the row in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mohammad889/58scj0nr/5/)

This question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36377229/add-margin-between-row-elements-bootstrap) However I couldn't find a proper answer, because adding padding is not possible in my case.

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.item {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 item m-1">2</div>
    <div class="col-6 item">4</div>
  </div> 
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-8 item m-2">2</div>
    <div class="col-4 item">1</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well u can do this by adding a new div inside ur col

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.item {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6"><div class="m-1 item">2</div></div>
    <div class="col-6"><div class="m-1 item">4</div></div>
  </div> 
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-8 "><div class="m-2 item">4</div></div>
    <div class="col-4"><div class="m-2 item">6</div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that's a good go around solution , i didn't thought about that.... thanks